# label1 doesn't exist in current context:asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a project in which I create 2 int variables m = 5 and s =2 and assign datetime objects minutes to m and seconds to s. Then concatenate each to a string var str and perform increments of + and - and * to obtain new values. This is actually my first project in asp.net and I'm using C# language that I'm learning as I practice. I don't quite understand this label1 doesn't exist in current context. I followed the examples in my learning tutors exactly. In this forum I found solution that's beyond my beginner scope and knowledge. But I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. I've been going in circles since yesterday. Thank you in advance. Here is the code.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
  <script runat="server">
  void Page_Load()
  {
  String str = "";
  int m, s;
  m = 5;
  s = 2;
  label1.Text = str; 
 m = 5;
 s = 2;
 str += "m+s" + (m+s) + "<br/>";
 label2.Text = str;
 m = 5;
 s = 2;
 str += "m-s" + (m-s) + "<br/>";
 label3.Text = str;
 m = 5;
 s = 2;
 str += "m*s" + (m*s) + "<br/>";
 label4.Text = str;
 }

 </script>
<!Doctype html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <%--
 Heading
 Student: Schweidel Tyson;
 'File name: ex02.aspx
 --%>
 m = <%=DateTime.Now.Minute%><br>
 s = <%=DateTime.Now.Second%>
  <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"/></asp:Label>
 m+s = <%=str%>
 <asp:Label id="Label2" runat="server"/></asp:Label> 
 m-s = <%=str%>
 <asp:Label id="Label3" runat="server"/></asp:Label> 
m*s = <%=str%>
<asp:Label id="Label4" runat="server"/></asp:Label> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does this code compile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page, you're creating a label with an `id` of `Label1`. Then in your code-behind, you're referring to it as `label1` (note the difference in case).

The issue here is that `Label1 != label1`. Change either the declaration or the code so these match, and you should no longer have this error.

As an additional note, you should really consider using better variable names, like `labelText`, `minutes`, `seconds`, etc. In my opinion this code is difficult to read, and formatted code with good names is much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I fixed the label issue. Thank you for you comment. I'm new to ASP.NET, so what does "code-behind" mean? I see the term a lot in my research.

Comment: @swydell do a google search if you are not familiar with basic `C# .net terms` there are lots of explanations on what `CodeFile vs CodeBehind` is on MSDN

Comment: I'll be doing a lot of google searches. One more thing. Now I'm getting '"The name 'str' doesn't exist in current context." The error is on line 39 where I coded m+s = <%=str%>. I removed the multiple declarations of String str = " ";

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exist in current context usually in my limited xp means there is a scope issue. Simply means that the place you are referencing the variable can't "see" the variable. Remember that if something is inside curly braces something refrencing from outside cant see it.

Comment: the person below me is right. I didn't read the code just the error. My apologies

Comment: Thank you for your comment on "Scope". What do you recommend for accessing or referencing variables not in scope. Or how to make them accessible? Would I need to use access modifiers, like protected, private? I'm still learning, if it sounds dumb :).

Comment: @swydell Check out http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx for a decent explanation on variable scope.